# Multiple Polylines not rendering when cordinates array is updated

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying make a multi colored polyline. I have been able to do it successfully before with Vue.js but now we are adding it to react native app and its not working as i expected in React js.

I am making multiple polylines, each line (segment) has multiple points. I have a structure like this:

groups: [ { key: 'BLUE', cordinates: [] }, key: 'GREEN', cordinates: [] ];

Now each key represent a color and cordinates is an array of cordinates. Now when I loop it like this:

```
{
    this.state.groups.map((group, index) => {

        return (
            <Polyline
                key={index}
                coordinates={group.Points}
                strokeColor={
                    group.Key === "GREEN" ? "#0F0" : "#000"
                    // "#000"
                    // group.Key === "G"
                } // fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
                strokeColors={[
                    '#7F0000',
                    '#00000000', // no color, creates a "long" gradient between the previous and next coordinate
                    '#B24112',
                    '#E5845C',
                    '#238C23',
                    '#7F0000'
                ]}
                strokeWidth={6}
            />
        );

    })
}
```

The problem is it works! perfectly but it doesnt draw the last polyline which is being updated. So for example there are 10 segments in this polyline. Now after 3 are drawn and loop is on 4th segment, its pushing each cordinate in the last group with a delay of 30 ms. I added delay to show it animated. Now it won't draw on map untill all cordinates of the 4th segments are pushed. When its done, and 5th segment is started, 4th segment shows perfectly but now 5th segment stops working.

I know that points are being perfectly added because I have added a Camera as well and I change its center to be last point that was pushed in groups/segments.

Group/Segments loop:

```
addPoint(group, point) {

        var data = this.state.data;

        if (group <= (data.length - 1)) {

            var g = data[group];

            // console.log('g', g);

            if (point <= (g.Item2.length - 1)) {

                var p = g.Item2[point];

                var {groups} = this.state;

                // console.log('groups,', groups);

                groups[group].Points = groups[group].Points.concat({
                    longitude: p.longitude,
                    latitude: p.latitude,
                });

                this.MapView.animateCamera({
                    center: {
                        latitude: p.latitude,
                        longitude: p.longitude,
                    },
                    duration: 100,
                    zoom: 15,
                });

                point++;

                setTimeout(() => {

                    this.addPoint(group, point);

                }, 300);

            } else {

                point = 0;
                group++;

                if (group < this.state.data.length - 1) {

                    var key = this.state.data[group].Item1;

                    console.log('key', key);

                    var groups = this.state.groups.concat({
                        Key: key,
                        Points: [],
                    });

                    this.setState({
                        groups: groups,
                    })

                }

                setTimeout(() => {

                    this.addPoint(group, point);

                }, 300);

            }

        } else {

            console.log('last group reached');

        }

    }
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: it is working for android ? I mean in android devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was whenever I updated the coordinates array of any polyline, it had to re-render whole thing which was performance wise very poor decision.

I solved it by making a custom polyline component which maintains its own coordinates array. Implemented an inner timeout function which pushes coordinates incrementally. This solved the problem and its now super easy to use.

You can read more about this here: [multi colored gradient polyline using google maps on react native](http://www.techcuriosity.net/react-native-google-maps-multi-colored-polyline/)